# JavaScript function that divides two numbers

Tags: javascript, function

In JavaScript, how would you write a function that takes two numbers as parameters, say n1 and n2, and divides the first number by the second number? For example, divide(6, 2) should return 3.

Comment: `const divide=(n1,n2)=>n1/n2`

Comment: For documentation purposes, please accept the answer if it helped you or give your input regarding the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function works properly:

```
function divide(input1, input2) {
   var result = 0;
   s1= parseInt(input1);
   s2= parseInt(input2);
   if (s2!=0){
      result=s1/s2;
   }
   return result;
}
```

Trying `divide(6, 2)` result is `3`.